# The V8 JavaScript engine and string literals

Tags: javascript, v8

When the V8 engine runs a script that refers to multiple string literals with the same contents, will it create a single location in memory for the string, towards which all the expressions will point to? Or will a separate memory location be allocated for every expression?

For instance, consider this little script:

```
let a = "asdf"
let b = "asdf"
```

After this runs, in the engine's internal representation of the variables, will a and b refer to the same location in memory?

(Bonus question: Is this behavior the same in other JavaScript engines, such as Internet Explorer's?)

Comment: It might, and it might not. There's no way you can tell.

Comment: It should have separate memory location. If you have same memory location how can you change value of one variable?

Comment: I believe that strings in JS are immutable, so sharing memory locations wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I hope the duplicate answers your question well enough. If you want a specific answer about the code example in the V8, please remove your bonus question and I'll happily reopen and wait for @jmrk to jump in (please ping me)

Comment: I've taken a look at 2 very long strings in Chrome memory profiler. When the when the strings are the same (e.g. a==b), memory is at 2.5mb. If I change the code and make the strings different by one char, then memory is at 3.5mb. So it would seems that the compiler optimizes for same string literals.

Comment: No the linked answer is perfect, thank you @Bergi!